# How to execute sql commands with more than 1 line in c#

Tags: c#, sql

I want to know how to execute more than one SQL command at once.

At this moment I'm doing it like this:

```
using (SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT nome FROM teste";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;

        sqlConnection1.Open();

        // execute the command
        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(rdr["name"].ToString()); 
        }
    }
}
```

But how can I do to execute

```
use [databaseX]
SELECT nome FROM teste
```

in my c# program?

Comment: You don't need to execute that line; you can set the database you want to use in your `connectionString`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Separate multiple statements with a semicolon (`;`).

(BTW, the `use` statement is generally not needed because it's set in your connection string.)

Answer (score 3):

Use `@` to declare the string:

```
cmd.CommandText = @"
    use [databaseX]
    SELECT nome FROM teste
";
```

OR actually escape the line break:

```
cmd.CommandText = "use [databaseX]\nSELECT nome FROM teste";
```

Answer (score 3):

SQL uses a `;` to seperate commands / queries.

```
SELECT * FROM Table1; SELECT * FROM Table2;
```

results in to result sets.